# Raspberry Pi - Windows 10 IoT - Visual Studio Debugger Old Version From PC V.S

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio-debugging, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to deploy simple Hello World application to Raspberry Pi 2 Windows 10 IoT Core. I can see that the Visual Studio Debugger services (2) are running. However, when I run the application in Remote Machine, it is throwing below error.

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'RPiWin10'. The remote debugger is older than this version of Visual Studio 2015, and Visual Studio is no longer compatible with it. Please upgrade your remote debugger to match Visual Studio.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Seems like my Visual Studio version on Raspberry Pi is older than my local machine's.

What is the default version of Visual Studio Debugger that comes with Windows 10 IoT Core for Raspberry Pi?
How can I upgrade the Visual Studio Debugger version on my Raspberry Pi? Is it possible!! or I have to downgrade my local machine's Visual Studio version?

Answer (score 3):

There is an updated version, you need to install a new image.

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm